# Is it wise to keep a MongoDB session open for the lifetime of an object?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a struct that abstracts MongoDB for specific objects in my system, and during the factory function for it I set a few variables like hostname and other connection information. At the moment in each of the `UserService`'s methods* it creates a new session, does what it needs to, then closes the session when it's done.

The system itself is the backend of a web application, so the lifetime of each `UserService` struct is usually only a few seconds at most, but more than one operation might be performed for each request that comes in. So I'm wondering whether to make `session` a member of the struct, initialise it when I create my `UserService`, and then ensure the request handler function that creates it calls a close function once it's done all the operations it needs to. I haven't been able to find anything that encourages or discourages this behaviour so I'm not really sure if the mgo package I'm using is designed that way.

This is my proposed code:

```
type UserService struct {
    callingUserId id.ID //The ID of the user calling this service.
    host string //The host name.
    session mgo.Session //The active session.
}

func NewUserService(userId id.ID) *UserService {
    nus := new(UserService)
    nus.callingUserId = userId
    nus.host = "localhost" //TODO change this to read from file or buffer.
    nus.session, sessionErr = mgo.Dial(nos.host)
    if sessionErr != nil {
        //TODO log error.
    }
    return nus
} 

func (us UserService) GetById(usrId id.ID) *users.User {        
    //TODO get a user from the database with the matching ID using the existing session.        
}
```

There will also be a function called `UserService.CloseSession`, which as I mentioned, will be called after all the required operations are done by the handler function that creates the service.

Does anyone know if this is a sensible idea or should I just call `mgo.Dial` in every function on `UserService`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening a connection to MongoDB or any other DB is an expensive task that should be done once and kept operative as much as possible inside your service.

You have three options:

1. A local package level MongoDB instance.
2. Using Contexts and  Composing Handlers.
3. A method receiver which holds the MongoDB Instance.

This is a [very informative blog post](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access) for handling DBs connections.
Take a look to this [example](https://medium.com/@matryer/production-ready-mongodb-in-go-for-beginners-ef6717a77219#.h2p93mbok), especially for MongoDB

Comment: I know it's premature optimisation, but in your opinion is it better to have one session per service or a global session used by multiple services?

Comment: You can share and copy the mongo session among services. Btw. If you think the answer is OK.. Could you please select accept it?

Comment: I object to always reuse a single session. All operations would share a single stack server side (which has a fixed size of 1MB). Actually, from my experience the best performance is to be gained by `.Copy()` a session (which retains authentication) in a "StructFactory" for large operations.